# PHP SERVER SSL_CLIENT_CERT disappears for when navigating pages

Tags: apache-2.4, docker, php-fpm, mod-ssl

I am containerizing a legacy webservice that use SSL Client certificate validation.  I have an apache 2.4 container and a PHP 7.4 FPM container.

My apache virtual host conf looks like

```
...
<VirtualHost *:8443>
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/myapp
  ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ fcgi://php:9000/var/www/html/myapp/$1
  SSLEngine on
  ....
  SSLCACertificateFile <PATH TO CA>
  SSLVerifyClient optional
  SSLVerifyDepth 2
  ...
  <Files ~ "\.(cgi|shtml||phtml|php3?)$">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
  </Files>
  <Directory "/var/www/html/myapp">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars +ExportCertData
    Require all granted
    DirectoryIndex index.php
  </Directory>
  ...
</VirtualHost>
....
```

index.php

```
<?
   print_r($_SERVER);
?>
<html>
....
  <a href=go.php><img name=go src=="go.png" alt="GO!"></a>
....
</html>
```

Go.php

```
<?php
  print_r($_SERVER);
  ... DO Authoriztion stuff with SSL_CLIENT_CERT ...
?>
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: 3.4"
services:
  apache:\
    image: myappApache
    depends_on: php
    networks:
      - frontend
      - backend
    ports:
      - "80:8080"
      - "443:8443"
    volumes:
      - ./myapp/:/var/www/html/myapp:rw
  php:
    image: myappPHP
    networks:
      - backend
    volumes:
      - ./myapp/:/var/www/html/myapp:to
  networks:
    frontend:
    backend:
```

When I navigate to my index.php and print out the value of `_SERVER` with `print_r($_SERVER)`  I can see `[SSL_CLIENT_CERT] => -----BEGIN CERTIFICARTE----- ... -----END CERTIFICATE-----`.  However when I click on the link that on that page which takes me to a second page on the website the `SSL_CLIENT_CERT` is missing from `_SERVER`.  Other SSL Related items are missing as well

- SSL_SESSION_RESUMED
- SSL_SESSION_ID
- SSL_SERVER_A_SIG
- SSL_SERVER_A_KEY
- SSL_SERVER_I_DN

How do I keep `_SERVER` configuration settings from disappearing between pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why this worked.  But I moved the `SSLOptions +StdEvnVars +ExportCertData` outside of the `Directory` group and that seemed to fix things.